# Find third purchase without window function

Tags: mysql, sql

I came across this question:

> Given a revenue transaction table that contains user_id, timestamp,
>   and revenue, how would you find the third purchase of every user?

I know how to use window function to solve it, but I don't know how to solve it without window function. For example, correlated subquery.

If we want to find `n` th purchase, does your method work?

Comment: In Oracle would be something like so: select * 
  from ( select a.*, rownum rnum
           from ( YOUR_QUERY_GOES_HERE -- including the order by ) a
          where rownum <= N_ROWS )
 where rnum >= N_ROWS

Comment: do you also not want to emulate how row number works, using variables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In MySQL, I would use variables:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@u = user_id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@u := user_id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from (select t.*
            from transactions t
            order by user_id, timestamp
           ) t cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @u := -1) params
     ) t
where rn = 3;
```

That said, the old-fashioned SQL method is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from transactions t
where 3 = (select count(*)
           from transactions t2
           where t2.user_id = t.user_id and t2.timestamp <= t.timestamp
          );
```

Comment: Can you explain how this '3 =' works? or let me know the jargon so that I can search.

Comment: @John Hass: For each record in transaction the subquery counts how many transactions until then for that user. If it's 3 then this is the third transaction, otherwise not. `3 = (query)` simply compares the number three with the query result (the count).